# Authorizing a PHP web app + GDAL app to use Google services via OAuth2

Tags: google-oauth, gdal

I'm coding a PHP application that access data stored in Google Maps Engine. I've created a *Client ID for web applications* in the API console. So, I can authorize my app to access my GME data with [Google API PHP client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client). No problem so far.

My web application, at one specific moment, **call a system binary (ogr2ogr)** that also needs to access the data stored in Google Maps Engine. So, I pretended to use the [GME driver](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GMEDriver) and pass as config parameters:

- client id, client secret and api key (from the client id I created in API console)
- auth token and refresh token (from authorization response)

But here comes the problem:

**When I ty to call ogr2ogr using the previous authorization parameters, it returns a HTTP 400 error: Attempt to use a OAuth2 authorization code multiple times. Looks like the refresh token I pass is not valid**.

Going deeper in the problem, I found something I don't understand: **Google API console** allows you to create *Client ID for Web Applications*, but **does not make a difference between client-side application and server side applications**. And the Google OAuth2 documentation makes that difference:

- [Google OAuth2 flow for client-side applications](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent)
- [Google OAuth2 flow for web server applications](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer)

So, theoretically, **the client id I've created is for client-side application, and I'm using it with a server side app (PHP)**

So, my questions:

- **How can I create a client id in API console that I can use for both: PHP application and ogr2ogr binary** (I've tested the ogr2ogr binary with a *Client ID for installed applications* and it works perfectly, but that client id cannot be used for the PHP app).
- Why the API console doesn't make a difference between client id for client-side web apps and server-side web apps, like the documentation does? Clearly, I'm misunderstanding something. For example, [this tutorial](http://enarion.net/programming/php/google-client-api/google-client-api-php/) uses a *Client ID for web applications* for PHP code (but just for a web app, not for calling another program that also needs authorization)

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, you are trying to use a server-side authentication key using the client-side authentication flow, this won't work. What you need to do is instead to pass your Access token to the GDAL GME driver.

You can do it in one of the following ways:

1. Just add a `access=<your access token>` parameter to the "file name" that you use with ogr2ogr (the string starting with "GME:").
2. You can also use the GME_ACCESS_TOKEN environment variable.

This will shortcut the OAuth2 flow, and the program won't actually to an AOuth2 authentication flow, but simply re-use the authentication token that your PHP script generated. This works since you are making the request from the same machine and before the token expires.

This is (now) also documented in http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GMEDriver

Comment: Cool! Do I have to update GDAL from trunk and recompile it in order to use this?